# Add youtube comments with youtube API and node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, youtube, youtube-data-api

I managed to fetch video data from a channel but when it try to add comments to a video, I fail. So at some point I can read data successfully.

I have read that docummentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/insert

And I'm not sure if I did the parameters correctly.

Besides Node.js and Express I'm using the request-promise package for promises if that's worth to mention.

```
const optionsComment = {
      method: 'POST',
      uri: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads',
      qs: {
        part: 'snippet',
        'snippet.channelId': 'a channel id',
        'snippet.videoId': 'some video id',
        'snippet.topLevelComment.snippet.textOriginal': 'a nice message',
        key: "my key"
      },
      json: true
  };

  rp(optionsComment)
  .then(result=>{
    console.log("result of adding comment:", result);
  })
  .catch(function(err){
    console.log("error during add comment");
    console.log(err);
  });
```

When I run the code I get this error:

> error during add comment
>
> { StatusCodeError: 401 - {"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"required","message":"Login Required","locationType":"header","location":"Authorization"}],"code":401,"message":"Login Required"}}
> at new StatusCodeError

Even if I'm logged in and try to comment my own video I get this error.

Maybe someone can give me a hint.

Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by `im logged in`? Was it through OAuth2?

Comment: Oh yes. Im using passport.js and the youtube authentication with it.

Comment: i think the problem is somewhere at the "qs" json element. Since the example of the google documentation looks different but i couldnt figure out how to write it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd similar issue as yours, sending the `access_token` in `qs` fixed it for me.

```
'use strict';

let request = require('request');

const sourceId = '< youtube video id>';
const comment_id = 'the comment id';
const comment = 'actual comment';

new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  request({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads',
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Request-Promise'
    },
    body: {
      "snippet": {
        "videoId": sourceId,
        "channelId": comment_id,
        "topLevelComment": {
          "snippet": {
            "textOriginal": comment
          }
        }
      }
    },
    qs: {
      part: 'snippet',
      access_token: token
    },
    json: true
  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) {
      console.log('body', body);
      console.log('error in when posting comment ', error.stack);
      return reject(error);
    }
    return resolve(body);
  });
});
```

Comment: but how to get access_token ?